# Widgets + Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, widget

**An overview:** I'm trying to create a homescreen widget for Android that takes assignments and displays them in a list.

**The problem:** Querying the database takes longer than the program takes to call `getCount()`.

**The code:**

```
public class WidgetViewFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Database.dueAssignmentDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Assignment assignment = userSnapshot.getValue(Assignment.class);
                    assignments.add(assignment);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

...

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.d("Widget", "getCount: " + assignments.size());
        return assignments.size();
    }

...
```

**tl;dr** expecting `getCount()` to return anything other then 0, returns 0.

Comment: You sure you are getting values from database

Comment: @Yupi Yeah. I logged during getCount() and after the database was done querying, and I was getting values from the database. It was just triggering AFTER getCount().

Comment: FWIW (I've never created an app widget): Looking at the [App Widget Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#fresh), it seems like you need to call `AppWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()` in `onDataChange()` to trigger a refresh of your widget after your Firebase data loads.

Comment: @BobSnyder That worked! Thanks a ton man.

Comment: For future readers: make sure to call `AppWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()` within `onDataChange()` of your `ValueEventListener`. Do __not__ call it within `onDataSetChanged()` of your `RemoteViewsFactory` since, in short, that will cause problems. The method names are unfortunately very similar and I  mixed them up at first.